# Get the highest key in array less than 'x'

Tags: php, arrays

How do I get the highest key from an array where the key is less than a given number?

```
$arr = array('10' => 'a', '20' => 'b', '30' => 'c', '40' => 'd', '50' => 'e');
$max = max(array_keys($arr));
```

Which will set `$max` to '50'. But if I want to get the max key where the key is less than '38', is there a way to avoid going through a loop?

Comment: What's the problem with loop?

Comment: A loop would be better as you know you can start at 37.  If that's found you're done, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter) to get the array with keys less than 38, and the use `max()`.

**PHP 7.4+**

```
$arr = ['10' => 'a', '20' => 'b', '30' => 'c', '40' => 'd', '50' => 'e'];
$threshold = 38;

// Keep elements under condition:
$limit = array_filter($arr, fn($key) => $key < $threshold,  ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

$max = max(array_keys($limit)); // get the max of remain keys.
var_dump($max);
```

Outputs:

```
int(30)
```

**Before PHP 7.4**

```
$threshold = 38;
$arr = ['10' => 'a', '20' => 'b', '30' => 'c', '40' => 'd', '50' => 'e'];

$filtered = array_filter($arr, function($key) use ($threshold) { return $key < $threshold; },  ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
$max = max(array_keys($filtered));
var_dump($max); // int(30)
```

Comment: Just an FYI for OP, `array_filter()` is still a loop behind the scenes, but this is still a great solution and I don't think there is a way to do it without a loop

Comment: While, `min(max($a))` is a perfectly valid functional way of solving this problem it does come with a cost. That is to say `O(n*2)` in the worst case since you have to traverse the array twice, once with `array_filter` and once with `max`. Technically `array_filter` is just quicksort which is `O(log n)`, but `max` is always worst case `O(n)`. Not a huge difference from a loop that bails early when it hits the threshhold, but a difference to consider none the less. With that said I don't think the OP's primary concern here is to *avoid* the loop necessarily, but to get there quicker.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_filter()` to essentially do your (`for`/`foreach`/`while`)loop logic for you:

```
<?php
    $data = array('10' => 'a', '20' => 'b', '30' => 'c', '40' => 'd', '50' => 'e');
    # get the keys as an array
    $keys = array_keys($data);
    # define your criteria
    $max = 38;

    # use array_filter to return elements lower than $max
    $belowMax = array_filter(
        $keys, 
        function($num) use ($max)
        {
            return $num < $max;
        } 
    );

    # use max() to get highest value
    $highest = max($belowMax);

    # print highest key under $max
    echo '<pre>'. print_r($highest, 1). '</pre>';
```

See [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/fJFmM)

Comment: FWIW, `array_filter` loops. While you may not have written a loop, you have still traversed the entire array with `array_filter`. So it's, at best, misleading to say you can do it without a loop.

Comment: Minor note: the [PHP standard](https://github.com/php-fig-rectified/fig-rectified-standards/blob/master/PSR-2-R-coding-style-guide-additions.md#commenting-code) for inline comments is `//` rather than shell style comments with `#`, although it is valid.

Comment: @BadHorsie true, I just personally prefer hashes, lazy dev so 1 char less to type has much more appeal to me haha :)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy with a loop since you know where to start:

```
for($key = 38, $max = 0; !$max; $key--, $max = $arr[$key] ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have both a greather-than **AND** less-than requirement, `max` doesn't satisfy your requirements by itself. You'll need both conditions checked as you traverse the array. You can't avoid a loop, in the sense that you **must** traverse the array to find the value, but you *can* bail early once both conditions are satisfied. So your worst case complexity here is `O(n)`.

```
function getKeyRange(array $array, $min, $max = 0) {

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        if ($key > $max && $key < $min) {
            $max = $key;
        }

        if ($key >= $min) {
            return $max;
        }
    }

}

echo getKeyRange([10 => 'a', 20 => 'b', 30 => 'c', 40 => 'd', 50 => 'e'], 38); // 30
```

Comment: Whoever down voted feel free to enlighten me why you felt it necessary to down vote a perfectly legitimize answer.

Comment: I am definitely engaging my Saint Mary MacKillop (saint of the abused) protocol on this answer.  This answer must not be negatively scored because it is correct, and will perform better than any answer which contains `array_filter()` since it has a conditional early return built in.  It is crime against the asker and researchers when the best answer on the page has the lowest score.  Why deliberately mislead readers by negatively biasing the page sorting algorithm!

Answer (score -1):

```
function getMaxKey($array, $max) {
    $filtered = array_filter(array_keys($array), function($key) use ($max) {
        return $key < $max;
    });
    return max(array_keys($filtered));
}

// Usage
$max = getMaxKey($arr, 38);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to how this will solve OP's problem.